# Infinite order of a quotient of functions' groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, infinite-groups

Let $G=\{f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb Z\}$ be a commutative group with the following operation for $f,g\in G$ and $n\in\mathbb N$:
$$(f+g)(n):=f(n)+g(n).$$
I've already showed that the set $H=\{h:\in G:\forall n\in\mathbb N,h(n)\in2\mathbb Z\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.
The second request of the exercise asks me to show that $|G:H|$ is infinite.

This part of the problem seemed to be quite easy but I can't find a consistent way to prove this.
I've showed that $H\trianglelefteq G$, since $\forall n\in N$ the conjugated of a generic $h\in H$ with an element of $f\in G$ is such that
$$(\bar f+h+f)(n)=(-f+h+f)(n)=-f(n)+h(n)+f(n)\in H.$$
I was trying to find a surjective homomorphism $\varphi: G\to X$ such that $H$ is the Kernel of this homomorphism in order to apply the first isomorphism theorem with $G/H\cong\varphi (G)\cong X$, where X is an infinite group, but I can't find it. Using the corespondence theorem on $G/H$,supposing that $|G:H|$ is finite, also seems to be inconclusive.

I really thank you for the support.

Comment: In general if $X$ is a set, $G$ is a group, and $H$ a subgroup, the set $G^X$ of maps $X\to G$ is a group in the same fashion, and $H^X$, defined similarly (only those maps valued in $H$) is a subgroup, as can be directly checked. However it cannot be proved by describing it as a kernel, when $H$ is not a normal subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your idea, we can consider the map $\varphi \colon G \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z})^{\mathbb{N}}$ defined by $$\varphi(f) = \left( f(n) \bmod{2} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \, \text{.}$$ The map $\varphi$ is a surjective group homomorphism whose kernel is $H$, so it induces an isomorphism from $G/H$ to the group $(\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z})^{\mathbb{N}}$, which is infinite.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't so far from the solution. Using this idea, could we also show that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic taking the homomorphism (then showing that it is an isomorphism) $\psi$ such that $$\psi:G\overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow} H, \psi(f)=2f(n)$$

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, it works.

Comment: Can I express the map you wrote as a  $\Psi_{\alpha}$, where $\alpha:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z_2$ and $$\varphi(f)=\Psi_{\alpha}(f)= \alpha\circ f?$$

Comment: Yes, it is the same map. I even prefer the way you wrote it actually.